# What does 'kick back' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Want to **kick back** and relax without having to bust out your laptop?

I see this sentence in the dictionary on my phone. I don't understand what **kick back** means here.

Comment: You can use Google,  it's a nice dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, *kick back* is an expression which means, per [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/kick-back), simply

> to relax

It is used intransitively. The [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/kick-back) marks it as *especially North American English*, i.e. it is more commonly used in Canada and the U.S. than elsewhere.

[According to](https://www.etymonline.com/word/kickback) the Online Etymology Dictionary, this usage originated around 1975. The exact origin is unknown, but in the [EL&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7793) theories are posited that it refers to the motion of the legs when one reclines quickly, or that it is a compression of *kick off your shoes, lie back, and relax*, or a conflation of the latter with *sit back and relax* as U.S. airline pilots always seem to suggest to passengers.

I post this answer because the most common other senses of *kick back*, *kick-back*, or *kickback* are negative or violent, referring to violent motion, the recoil on a firearm, a type of bribery, or fighting. As always, context is essential to meaning. The sense of *kickback* as enjoying being comfortable, or doing nothing, is not used as a noun. Thus, there is a huge difference between the mayor asking you to kick back and the mayor asking you for a kick back.

Comment: Colloquially a "kick-back" is a bribe.

Comment: @WS2 But not in this case.